# Can only see icons that in the desktop. no global menu, no dash!

Tags: unity-dash, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn’t load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I just upgraded my 12.04 system to 12.10, but only seem to be able to access the applications for which i had shortcuts on the desktop. No sidebar or global menu show up at all.

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can try typing on a terminal (pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd>):

```
unity --reset
```

This will reset your unity settings.